# Angular form not validating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have the following form:

```
<form name="ff" ng-submit="formSubmit(ff)" role="form" class="form-horizontal" id="form-{{context.identifier}}" novalidate>
    <div class="col-xs-12 box-shadow">
      <div class="col-xs-6" style="margin-top: 1em;">
        <input type='hidden' name='nodeIdentifier' value='{{context.currentStep.identifier}}' />
        <input type='hidden' name='contextIdentifier' value='{{context.identifier}}' />
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-xs-4" for="requestor_name">Approve:</label>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <select name="form.field.decision">
              <option value="Approved">Approved</option>
              <option value="Denied">Denied</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-xs-4" for="form.field.reason">
            Reason:</label>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="reason" required minlength='4' maxlength='255'/>
          </div>
          <div ng-messages="ff.reason.$error" role="alert">
            <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a reason</div>
            <div ng-message="minlength, maxlength">
              Your reason must be between 4 and 255 characters long
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Here is the code to log what gets submitted in `formSubmit(data)`:

```
console.log("Data");
console.log(data);
```

My form is always showing valid.  Why is the angular validation not working?  I have included the nagular messages too.

Comment: Would you be able to put this is a plunker or fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You got no ng-model bound to your input fields. Looks like ngMessages needs those.

EDIT: found a comment on a tutorial, because I wasn't 100% sure:

- [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation-with-ngmessages) comment:

> fyi that not including the ng-model attribute on validated fields will
>   break the form validation

Comment: The model is rendered via a directive, so I guess I'll have to play with it to get it working.